# How to configure Firefox 'search in URL' bar faster

Tags: firefox

When I type a word e.g. 'cat' in Firefox URL bar, it takes a while (~ 1 min) before it redirects me to search engine result.

When I use Search box in Firefox or use 'Chrome', it redirects me search engine much faster.

Is there a way which allows me to search faster in URL bar?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you experience the same delay if you type multiple words and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>? If not, the reason probably is that with a single word Firefox first tries to lookup/check whether any domain by that name exists, and only when that fails does it redirect to the default search engine URL. However, with multiple words it goes to the search engine directly since spaces are unsafe in URLs and must be encoded.

One possible way to make searches faster for single words from the Location Bar might be to add a keyword via the [Manage Search Engines](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/search-bar-easily-choose-your-search-engine#w_managing-search-engines) dialog:

[image: 1]

This would of course require you to type "g cat" instead of just "cat", which is why I prefer to simply press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> and start typing in the Search Bar directly.

---

**Edit:** As requested, to turn off the Domain Guessing feature:

1. In the Location Bar, type `about:config` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
2. If the "This might void your warranty!" warning page appears, click "I'll be careful, I promise!" to continue
3. In the Search field, type `fixup`
4. Double-click `browser.fixup.alternate.enabled` to set its value to `false`

Comment: No. If I put multiple words, the speed is fine. How can I disable 'with a single word Firefox first tries to lookup/check whether any domain by that name exists'?

Comment: @michael: Check the edit.